# Java WebService throwing javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException with Invalid Endpoint Interface

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to call a WebService.  I built the client jar from the published WSDL.  When I make the WebService call, I get a WebServiceException.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: The Endpoint validation failed to validate due to the following errors:  :: Invalid Endpoint Interface
```

The exception is listing the methods that the WSDL exposes and the methods the client thinks should be there.  In the list from the client, there are a couple of null values instead of method names.

```
wsdl operations = [getEntity getBrokers addBrokerPermissions removeBrokerPermissions addAgencyPermissions updateTaxIdUserAuth updateTaxIdFacets removeAgencyPermissions addBrokerUser isValidTaxId getBrokerConfirmationId addConfirmationId getBrokerByConfirmationId confirmBrokerRegistration getBrokerConfirmations addAgencyUser getAgencies approveAgencyRegistration rejectAgencyRegistration getAgencyConfirmations ] 

dispatch operations = [getBrokers addBrokerUser removeBrokerPermissions getAgencyConfirmations getBrokerConfirmations addBrokerPermissions approveAgencyRegistration isValidTaxId getBrokerByConfirmationId null addConfirmationId addAgencyUser confirmBrokerRegistration rejectAgencyRegistration addAgencyPermissions getBrokerConfirmationId null getEntity getAgencies removeAgencyPermissions ]
```

The nulls should be either updateTaxIdUserAuth or updateTaxIdFacets.  I have looked at my client, and the methods are in there, and they are annotated with @WebMethod.

I am running on WAS 7.0.

Comment: Please be very detailed about how you generated the Java client code.

Comment: I used RAD to generate the client from the WSDL.

Comment: And how did the WSDL come into existance?

Comment: It was generated when the web service was written.  I am getting it by hitting the web service URL with ?WSDL passed in so that it will return me its WSDL.

Comment: Eclipse (and most likely also RAD) has a web service explorer, allowing you to test an existing web service just by pointing to the WSDL.  It is a good start to find out if the server part or client part is broken.  If the client part is broken, consider learning how to use "wsimport" in the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when the wsdl used by the client is not up to date.
F.E. when the server adds some methods after sharing wsdl with the client.

You can go in WAS configuration, adding the following property:

```
Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties
jaxws.ignore.extraWSDLOps = true
```

This tells WAS not to consider that condition as an error.
Should solve the issue.

Marco